# How To Create a Reusable Form Vue Component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Let's say I want to create a contact form. In this contact form, a user can have multiple addresses. I would think that this is a perfect opportunity to use a Vue Component so that I don't have to create redundant address form fields. I would then be able to use this component in different areas of a website, say on edit, create, etc....

How would I go about creating a form component that a parent can use and have values from that form get added to an addresses array? Also, I would like to be able to populate this form with existing values if it's being edited.

I've tried different things but nothing I've tried seems to work. Any ideas? I've searched Stack and Google but haven't been able to find an answer.

Here is some starting code of what I'm trying to accomplish (crude example). Of course, I would allow a user to dynamically add multiple addresses on creation/edit but I would also on edit of the form loop through the addresses data to display each address component but this is just a quick non-working setup to get my point across.

### AddressComponent.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <h4>Address</h4>
    <label>Address</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="address">

    <label>City</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="city">

    <label>State</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="state">
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            address: null,
            city: null,
            state: null
        }
    }
 }
</script>
```

### ContactForm.vue

```
<template>
    <h1>My Contact Form</h1>
    <form>
        <AddressComponent></AddressComponent> // Addresses[0]
        <AddressComponent></AddressComponent> // Addresses[1]
    </form>
</template>
<script>
import AddressComponent from '../components/AddressComponent'

export default {
    components: {AddressComponent},
    data() {
        return {
            addresses: [],
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this, pass in the data and then emit the change back to the parent.

```js
Vue.component('address-component', {
  template: '#address',
  props: ['data', 'index'],
  data() {
    return {
      item: {
        address: this.data.address,
        city: this.data.city,
        state: this.data.state
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    inputOccurred() {
      this.$emit('on-change', this.item, this.index)
    }
  }
});

//
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      addresses: [{
          address: '1 Stackoverflow Way',
          city: 'San Fran',
          state: 'California'
        },
        {
          address: '2 Stackoverflow Way',
          city: 'San Fran',
          state: 'California'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setAddress(value, index) {
      this.$set(this.addresses, index, value);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.14/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>My Contact Form</h1>

  <address-component 
    v-for="(address, index) in addresses" 
    :data="address" 
    :index="index"
    :key="index"
    @on-change="setAddress"
  ></address-component>

  <pre>{{ addresses }}</pre>
</div>

<template id="address">
   <div>
     <h4>Address</h4>
     <label>Address</label>
     <input type="text" v-model="item.address" @input="inputOccurred"/>

     <label>City</label>
     <input type="text" v-model="item.city" @input="inputOccurred"/>

     <label>State</label>
     <input type="text" v-model="item.state" @input="inputOccurred"/>
   </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks!