# How to split the content of a VueJS template in multiple files

Tags: vuejs2

In the example below, I'd like to keep the display of my application in the main file and the settings edition in separate files (one file per setting) for cleaner code and better readability.

```
<template>
  <div>

    <!-- KEEP DISPLAY IN MAIN FILE -->

    <!-- display myVar content -->
    <div>my var: {{ myVar }}</div>

    <!-- display myArray content -->
    <div v-for="(item, index) in myArray" :key="i">
      item: {{ item }}
    </div>

    <!-- display myObject content -->
    <div v-for="(item, index) in myObject['foo']" :key="i">
      item: {{ item }}
    </div>

    <!-- MOVE TO FILE A: myVar settings -->
    <input type="text" v-model="myVar" />

    <!-- MOVE TO FILE B: myArray settings -->
    <div v-for="(s, index) in myArray" :key="i">
      <input type="text" v-model="myArray[i]" @change="resetMyArray" />
    </div>

    <!-- MOVE TO FILE C: myObject settings -->
    <div v-for="(abc, index) in myObject.foo" :key="i">
      <input type="text" v-model="myObject.foo[index]" />
      <input type="text" v-model="myObject.bar[index]" />
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

How should I split this template into a multiple file ?

Comment: Maybe like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307357/how-to-create-a-reusable-form-vue-component/49308072#49308072

Comment: I don't want to add more logic to my code, just want to split the template in different files to make it more readable and easier to edit.

Comment: what you have is easy to read and edit.. in vue you create [components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) to abstract stuff, as link shows (how to pass and receive data from child to parent etc).

Comment: This minimal example is easy to read and edit, but the real code is actually much bigger. It's not recommended to change a parent components variable from a child component.

Comment: Your right, where are you seeing that ?

Comment: I've add more details to my example code to better show my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Main file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <PComponent :var="var1"/>
    <PComponent :var="var2"/>
    <PComponent :var="var3"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PComponent from './PComponent'

export default {
  components: {
    PComponent
  }
}
</script>
```

PComponent.vue:

```
<template>
   <p>var: {{ var }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['var']
}
</script>
```

Comment: you can also further improve the code by using `v-for`

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but it's not recommended to edit a variable used in main component from child component. I have updated the source code of my post to better show my problem.